# Transfer a domain to a new host

Tags: dns, web-hosting, host

I am using an OVH Server. It crashed yesterday and all the services (ssh, http, https, dns, smtp) are disabled. I contacted them and they said "We will try to fix it as soon as we can".

Sincerely I think that will need a long time to fix it (not very responsible); I needed to call several times for them to check the email I sent. What I want to do as a solution (not permanent) is to transfer the domain to a new host that I want to buy at Go Daddy. What I want to know is how long will it take for the domain to transfer; in some places I've read that it can last at least 5 days.

Comment: `"I need it urgently to be fixed"` - Consider this an important lesson learned.  If a service is business-critical, then don't go with some random free hosting company.  Something is only as important as you make it.  If the university budgeted *zero* resources to their website, then by definition it is *not* important.

Comment: How would *we* know? You should ask the responsible parties for a reliable answer.

Comment: To transfer a Web Hosting service to GoDaddy, you just need to login at domain control panel (Registrar control panel from where you purchased the domain name), point nameservers to GoDaddy. It will take 24 to 36 hours in DNS propagation. During DNS propagation period all your services will become inaccessible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a third-party customer service issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change in your domain name configuration (where u bought the domain example domain.com) the name server configuration to a new server you buy in go daddy that usually takes up to 24hr or if u have another website make a stealth url redirect to a different address where you can make a backup.